# Evaluating $\ i+i^2+i^3+i^4+\cdots+i^{100}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, summation

$$i+i^2+i^3+i^4+\cdots+i^{100}$$

I figured out that every four terms add up to zero where $i^2=-1$, $i^3=-i$, $i^4=1$, so
$$i+i^2+i^3+i^4 = i-1-i+1 = 0$$

Thus, the whole series eventually adds up to zero. But how do I approach this problem in a more mathematical way?

Comment: Hint:  It's a geometric series.

Comment: @lulu Actually, it doesn't converge. It oscillates between $0, i, i-1, -1$.

Comment: Second hint: your sum is equal to one.

Comment: @daruma  it's a finite sum.

Comment: You have a finite sum! The question for convergence is senseless.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. I missed that.

Comment: $i=e^{i\pi /4}$ is a $4$-th root of unity. So every sum of four consecutive power of $i$ ($i^n+i^{n+1}+i^{n+2}+i^{n+3}$) is null.

Comment: @lulu yeah I actually realize that this is a geometric series and that's what makes the problem as i can't approach it using the acknowledged geometric sequence formula. It just gets complex.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Somehow the correct answer in my textbook is 0

Comment: Just continue what you have and you'll see that every 4 consecutive terms adds up to zero, so the entire sum is zero.

Comment: Yes i was started with $1$ and not with $i$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt yup that's how i solved it but what if i wanted to apply the geometric series formula here where the common ratio is i, the first term is i and n=100 where $\ i^n $. 
How do i set this up?

Comment: Call it $S$.  Then $iS=S-i+i^{101}=S-i+i=S\implies S=0$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n i^k = \frac{i^{n+1}-1}{i-1}-1 = i\frac{i^n-1}{i-1}
$$

but $i^{100} = 1$ hence $\sum_{k=1}^{100} i^k = 0$

Answer (score 0):

A result that is useful in your case is $\sum_{k=1}^{n} z^k = \frac{z - z^{n+1}}{1 - z}$.
This follows from $(1 - z) \sum_{k=1}^{n} z^k = (1-z) (z + z^2 + \ldots + z^n) = z - z^{n+1}$, where I assumed $z \neq 1$.

In your case you get $\sum_{k=1}^{100} i^k =   \frac{i - i^{101}}{1 - i} = 0$, since $i^{101} = i$.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of originality:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{100} i^k 
=\sum_{p=0}^{24} (i^{4p+1} +i^{4p+2} +i^{4p+3} +i^{4p+4}) 
=\sum_{p=0}^{24} i^{4p}(i +i^2 +i^3 +i^4).$$
Knowing that $i +i^2 +i^3 +i^4 =i -1 -i +1= 0$ means your sum is also zero.